# How to consume multiple jobs in bull at the same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

In some cases there is a relatively high amount of concurrency, but at the same time the importance of real-time is not high, so I am trying to use bull to create a queue.

Because the performance of the bulk request API will be significantly higher than the split to a single request, so I want to be able to consume multiple jobs in a function to call the bulk API at the same time

Here is my current code (with nestjs):

```js
@Injectable()
export class DialogQueueService {
  constructor(
    @InjectQueue(QUEUE_NAME) public queue: Queue<DialogData>,
    private index: DialogsIndexService,
  ) {
  }

  async push(data: DialogData) {
    return this.queue.add(data, { jobId: data.id });
  }

  @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_30_SECONDS)
  async process() {
    const jobs = (
      await this.queue.getWaiting(await this.queue.getWaitingCount())
    ).filter(Boolean);
    const total = jobs.length;
    try {
        const response = await this.index.bulkInsert(
          jobs.map((job) => job.data),
        );
        jobs.forEach((job) => job.moveToCompleted(null, true, true));
        return response;
      } catch (err) {
        jobs.forEach((job) => job.moveToFailed(err, true));
      }
  }
}
```

The current code has the following problems

1. no queue events will be triggered
2. the queue stored in Redis will be stuck at `waiting` state (even if the job itself has been deleted), which will cause the `queue.getWaiting()` function to block the event loop for a long time

Is there any elegant way to consume multiple jobs in bull at the same time?

Comment: kind of interested in an answer too. I tried do the same with   @OnGlobalQueueWaiting() but i'm unable to get a lock on the job.